# How to get the endpoint ARN after the user re-install the android app for Amazon SNS?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

Currently I am using Amazon SNS for managing the google GCM , which is to push the notification.

The problem is , I can only get the endpoint ARN after create the end point like this,

but how can I check whether the user has register before? So I do not need to create one more record

and just use that old record. Thanks

The code below is a button for the user to turn on (register) / off (delete) the SNS in amazon

```
notify.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (prefs.getString("endpoint_arn", "").equals("")) {
            new AsyncTask() {
                @Override
                protected Object doInBackground(final Object... params) {                                       
                    try {
                        ((Activity) ctx).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                              public void run() {
                                  if (!pDialog.isShowing())
                                        pDialog.show();
                              }
                        });

                        String token = gcm.register(Constant.projectID);

                        CreatePlatformEndpointRequest per = new CreatePlatformEndpointRequest();
                        per.setToken(token);
                        per.setPlatformApplicationArn(Constant.platformARN);

                        CreatePlatformEndpointResult result = asnsc.createPlatformEndpoint(per);

                        editor.putString("endpoint_arn", result.getEndpointArn());
                        editor.commit();

                        ((Activity) ctx).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                              public void run() {
                                  notify_txt.setText(ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.on));
                                  if (pDialog.isShowing())
                                      pDialog.dismiss();
                              }
                        });

                    } catch (final Exception e) {
                        ((Activity) ctx).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                              public void run() {
                                  Log.d("test1","Registration Error:" + e.getMessage());
                                  Toast.makeText(ctx, getResources().getString(R.string.error),  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                  if (pDialog.isShowing())
                                      pDialog.dismiss();
                              }
                        });
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }.execute(null, null, null);

        } else {

            new AsyncTask() {
                @Override
                protected Object doInBackground(final Object... params) {                                       
                    try {
                        ((Activity) ctx).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                              public void run() {
                                  if (!pDialog.isShowing())
                                        pDialog.show();
                              }
                        });

                        DeleteEndpointRequest dPer = new DeleteEndpointRequest();
                        dPer.setEndpointArn(prefs.getString("endpoint_arn", ""));
                        asnsc.deleteEndpoint(dPer);
                        gcm.unregister();
                        editor.remove("endpoint_arn").commit();

                        ((Activity) ctx).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                              public void run() {
                                  notify_txt.setText(ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.off));
                                  if (pDialog.isShowing())
                                      pDialog.dismiss();
                              }
                        });

                    } catch (final Exception e) {
                        ((Activity) ctx).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                              public void run() {
                                  Log.d("test1","Delete Error:" + e.getMessage());
                                  Toast.makeText(ctx, getResources().getString(R.string.error),  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                  if (pDialog.isShowing())
                                      pDialog.dismiss();
                              }
                        });
                    }
                    return true;
                }


            }.execute(null, null, null);

        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Its most likely a logical issue resulting in endpoint duplication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge, even when user re-installs the app on the same device, device token generated by GCM will be same. If you've already registered the device with the token then SNS wont insert another record , instead it refers to the same. So no need to worry about registering user again to SNS with the device token.

Comment: It's not that pink. My testers receive each push 40 times as they often reinstall the application.